# Trying to understand the stack-like behaviour on recursive functions

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I'm reading the article about functions on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion), and I reached the Recursive part but I don't understand the last part that talks about using the stack-like behavior.

The example is that one:

```
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  console.log('begin:' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end:' + i);
}
foo(3);

// Output:

// begin:3
// begin:2
// begin:1
// begin:0
// end:0
// end:1
// end:2
// end:3
```

On that function, I understand when the `begin` log is shown but I don't when the `end` log is shown. Can someone help me and explain it me?

Comment: What did you expect when the `end` logs where shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically on each call to foo while it does the `i-1` it keeps the function open, it hasn't returned.  It keeps going hence the begin keeps getting called, once it reaches 0 the last function call returns.  Once this happens the other foo calls can start finishing as well.  They will finish from oldest to newest.

You can see a visulization of this using loupe by [Philip Roberts](https://github.com/latentflip).  [Here is a Loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZm9vKGkpIHsKICBpZiAoaSA8IDApCiAgICByZXR1cm47CiAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ2JlZ2luOicgKyBpKTsKICBmb28oaSAtIDEpOwogIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCdlbmQ6JyArIGkpOwp9CmZvbygzKTs%3D!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) of your example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I mark your answer as accepted for the link to the video. I watched and it helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, that loupe program is really useful for understanding how javascript timing and stack works.

Answer (score 2):

The `end` is showed right after EVERY `foo(i - 1);` has been called and processed.

Basically the process is:

1) calling  `foo(i)`
2) calling  `foo(i - 1)` n times;
Then, when `i` reaches `-1`: 
3) the deepest stack `return`s.
4) `console.log('end:' + i)` n times since it's still part of the function calls until `i` reaches `-1`;

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see it is probably to 'unfold' recursion and write it as sequence of consecutive calls:

```
foo(3);
begin:3
        foo(2);
        begin:2
                foo(1);
                begin:1
                        foo(0);
                        begin:0
                                foo(-1);
                                return;
                        end:0
                end:1
        end:2
end:3
```

'end:' strings are printed after reaching deepest recursion